# Wrong number of arguments to IF. Expected between 2 and 3 arguments, but got 4 arguments

Tags: google-sheets

Using google sheets and trying to say... If invetory level is less or equal than X then say "Re-Order";If Inventory leve cell is more than Y say "Overstocked", If more than X but less than Y say "Don't order". I am using the formula below, but I keep getting errors, can someone please help?

```
=IF((M3)<=O3;"Re-Order";IF(AND(M3)>O3;M3<=P3;"Don't Order";IF(AND(M3)>P3;"Overstocked")))
```

I am expecting to automatically calculate when to re-order products, when we have healthy inventory levels and when we are overstocked.

Comment: Your second `IF` has apparently two conditions specified: `AND(M3)>O3` and `M3<=P3`.  I assume that those should be combined together somehow.

Answer (score 0):

The `AND` function should be used with 2 or more arguments, try:

```cpp
=IF(M3<=O3;"Re-Order";
   IF(AND(M3>O3;M3<=P3);"Don't Order";
     IF(M3>P3;"Overstocked")))
```